# In Neo4j I want to obtain the path emerging from a particular node,I then want to iterate each node in the path and delete it based on stored action

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am doing a project of converting MySQL tables to Neo4j graph.After conversion I am replicating the delete action of the SQL Database using java in the graph.So when I delete a record in my SQL database,I want to delete the nodes related to that particular record.For example I am deleting from table Complaints with complaint_id=7.Complaint_Details is a child table of Complaints with  ON DELETE CASCADE Action .This further has another child table with ON DELETE SET NULL Action.So in the graph I want to delete the Complaint node with complaint_id = 7,Complaint_Details node with complaint_id =7 and the removal of the respective property of  its child nodes.

My current approach is to query the path from Node complaint with complaint_id 7 using
String cypherPath = "MATCH path=(n:" + tableName + "{" + columnName + ":" + PkValue + "})-[*]->(m) WHERE NOT EXISTS((m)-[]->()) RETURN path";
Then i am iterating through each node and checking the database for its action on deletion.Based on that action I am either deleting the node or removing a property.
This method takes up a lot of time (around 5s for 2000 records)
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you set up indexes on your columnName property for each of your tableName node types?

Comment: This could potentially be implemented very simply and efficiently in a single query, given the right graph data model. But you need to provide details of how how are you mapping the relevant SQL tables to equivalent graph nodes and relationships.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how it can be done in a single query.I have mapped the each table in SQL as a node type,the label of the node being the name of the table.Each column of the table being a property of the node. The relationships are created between the table and its corresponding child table on the property that the child table references.The name of the relationship is a combination of ReferncingTableNAme_ReferencingColumnofChildTable.

Comment: @Marj Yes i have set up indexes on the primary columnName properties for each of the tableName node types.But the performance increase is quite small.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I will assume your data model looks something like this (nodes can have more properties than shown):

```
(:Complaints {complaint_id: 7})-[:Complaint_Details_complaint_id]->(:Complaint_Details {complaint_id: 7, detail_id: 123})-->(:Foo {detail_id: 123})
```

Where `Foo` is just one of any number of labels for the child nodes of a `Complaint_Details` node.

In that case, when deleting a `Complaints` node you can also delete its `Complaint_Details` nodes and remove the `detail_id` properties of their children this way:

```
MATCH (c:Complaints)-[:Complaint_Details_complaint_id]->(d:Complaint_Details)
WHERE c.complaint_id = $complaint_id
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-->(f)
REMOVE f.details_id
DETACH DELETE d, c
```

The query assumes that the desired `complaint_id` value is passed as a `$complaint_id` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

Comment: I am actually implementing it using java.So I have a Data Structure which store the ON DELETE Action defined between  parent and child tables in MySQL. So i will obtain the paths originating from a particular node.Say I am deleting From Customer table with customer_id= 4 ,the child table complaint->complaints_details all have the ON DELETE CASCADE Constraint.In the graph,I have to delete all the complaint nodes with customer_id 4.the nodes Linked to these nodes which have a CASCADE constraint will further get deleted till the last node or SET NULL (only property deleted).

Comment: The reply you have given will only work in the case if all the relationships between parent and child tables have a ON DELETE CASCADE relationship and if i am aware of the depth of the child tables.Ami right? In the situation that I am referring to I am unaware of the number of child tables a particular node has.Because of this I am obtaining the all the paths from the node.For example all the paths from The Customer node with customer_id=4.

Comment: I assume the `Complaint_Details` table has ON DELETE CASCADE constraint with respect to the `Complaints` table, and that each `Complaint_Details` row can have any number of child nodes -- all of which have `ON DELETE SET NULL` with respect to the `Complaint_Details` table. My query will not handle paths from `Complaints` nodes that are greater than depth 2 (i.e., more than 2 relationships deep). Are you requiring an arbitrary depth?

Comment: Yes I am requiring an arbitrary depth.The relationship between each set of two consecutive nodes(tables in MySql) are also unknown to me.I am required to check in the data structure that is stored in-memory.